# What does this jQuery mean?

Tags: jquery

```
   $("#element").get(0).value =  v;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get's the first DOMElement that matches this query (similar to `getElementById('element').value = v`). <del>Really bad jQuery style.</del>

`$("#element").val(v);` could have been used to make it more jQuery-ish and independent of the input-type.

Comment: it's not really bad style. For instance, you need to check if an `checkbox` is checked, you should call `$jQueryRef[0].checked` rather than `$jQueryRef.is(':checked')`

Comment: @jAndy is correct, it's not bad style at all.  In fact, `$("#element").get(0).value` or `$("#element")[0].value` is more efficient if you know what you're doing. This is because jQuery runs several checks to ensure cross browser compatibility for certain element types, something that is redundant for things like `<input type="text">` because all browsers behave the same for those elements.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly valid to use the native properties available in DOM elements instead of jQuery methods.

With [`get()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/)  you're extracting the DOM element from the jQuery object, then using its native `value` property to set the new value.

An equivalent that I would prefer to use would be:

```
$("#element")[0].value =  v;
```

...which would accomplish the exact same thing, but does so directly via the DOM element's index.